# Почему не срабатывает код Java

Tags: java

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int life, money, bet;
            money = 100;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (scan.nextLine() == "balance") {
                System.out.print("U have" + money);
            }
            if(scan.nextLine() == "play"){
                System.out.print("Write ur bet.");
            bet = scan.nextInt();
                double a = Math.random();
                if(a==1){
                    money = money+bet;
                    System.out.print("Вы выйграли. Ваш баланс: "+money);
                }
                if(a==0){
                    money = money-bet;
                    System.out.print("Вы проиграли. Ваш баланс: "+money);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Что тут не правильно? Не читает команды типу balance и т.д. Так-же не выводит ничего.

Comment: Вместо `==` используйте `.equals("balance")`

Comment: Спасибо. А напомните как сделать что бы консоль не закрывалась а длилась бесконечно.

Comment: Либо просто [как тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032118/make-the-console-wait-for-a-user-input-to-close), либо еще проще `scan.next();` в конце.

Comment: Если пишете "выйграли", то нужно писать "пройграли", а то как-то непоследовательно получается.

Comment: @Эникейщик, пардон, не так прочитал, вопрос снят xD